# Why does VBA HTTP Post Work but .Net HTTPClient Request Fails

Tags: vb.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a bit of a puzzle that has been driving me insane for the past few days.  I have a simple VBA based HTTP Post using "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0" which works, however my implemntation of HttpClient in .Net fails with 'The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.'  Can someone please clarify what is happening here?  What do I need to do to get my httpclient implementation to work?

Here is the VBA Funciton:

```
Public Function GetScenarioData(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal startTime, ByVal endTime, ByVal TagName As String) As String

    Dim objrequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim token As String
    Dim json As Object
    Dim body As String
    Dim scenCrit As Criteria
    Dim query As String
   
    Set objrequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    strUrl = ws.Range("url")
    blnAsync = True
   
    With objrequest
        .Open "POST", strUrl, blnAsync
        
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "Accept: application/csv"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode("username" + ":" + "password")
        query = "q=SELECT ""tagname"",""value"" AS ""ActivePower"" FROM ""dbpart1"".""dbpart2"".""dbpart3"" WHERE TIME >= '" & startTime & "' AND time < '" & endTime & "' AND ""tagname""='" & TagName & "'"
        .send query
        'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
        While objrequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = Replace(.responseText, "\", "")
        strResponse = Mid(strResponse, 2, Len(strResponse) - 1)
    End With
    
    GetScenarioData = strResponse
End Function
```

and here is the vb.net function:

```
 Public Async Function Query(ByVal content As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As Task(Of String)

      Dim authenticate As String = ""
      Dim requestMsg As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _client.BaseAddress)
      Dim response As HttpResponseMessage
      Dim encoded As String

      Try
           Dim encodeThis = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}")
           encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encodeThis)

           requestMsg.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded)
           requestMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/csv")
           requestMsg.Content = New StringContent(content, Text.UTF8Encoding.Default, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
           response = Await _client.SendAsync(requestMsg)
           If (response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
                Return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
           End If
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      Finally

      End Try

 End Function
```

So subsequent to comments made by 'Selvin' I wound up reading about the credential cache, and have now modified my code to incorporate this functionality however still no joy, still getting the 407 error.  Having never encountered the proxy issue before I was unsure about what credentials were required in the credential cache, the credentials for the URI that I am targeting, or my local Windows credentials, so I have tried both with exactly the same negative result.

```
Private _clientHandler As HttpClientHandler
Private _credCache As New CredentialCache
```

...

```
 Public Sub CreateHttpClient(ByVal target As String)

      Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(target)

      'Only create the http client if one doesn't already exist   
      If _client Is Nothing Then
           _credCache.Add(uri, "Negotiate", New NetworkCredential("username", "password"))
           _clientHandler = New HttpClientHandler() With {.Credentials = _credCache, .PreAuthenticate = True}
           _client = New HttpClient(_clientHandler) With {.Timeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)}
           _client.BaseAddress = uri
      End If
 End Sub

 Public Async Function Query(ByVal content As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As Task(Of String)

      Dim authenticate As String = ""
      Dim requestMsg As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _client.BaseAddress)
      Dim response As HttpResponseMessage
      Dim encoded As String

      Try
           Dim encodeThis = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}")
           encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encodeThis)

           requestMsg.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded)
           requestMsg.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/csv")
           requestMsg.Content = New StringContent(content, Text.UTF8Encoding.Default, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
           response = Await _client.SendAsync(requestMsg)
           If (response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
                Return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
           End If
      Catch ex As Exception
           Throw
      Finally

      End Try

 End Function
```

Comment: Prolly because you have some system wide proxy setting which `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` apply and dotnet `HttpClient` doesn't ... it is hard to say as if there would be only basic auth on server this code should work (well, I would use `new FormUrlEncodedContent(new {{ "q" : "SELECT...."}})` )

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, the 407 error was due to our company proxy blocking the request.  The url in question has now been routed differently, and this opened up the endpoint.